# Python is throwing error for a file path inside the Project folder where it is not supposed to and seems to be a python glitch

Tags: python, working-directory, project-folder

Python is throwing some inconsistent error for a file reference inside the Project folder based on 'Working Directory' in the script configuration which is very weird

**My Project Structure as follows**

[image: My Project Structure as follows]

**config_utils.py**

```
f = ''

def config_init():

    global f

    txt_dir = '../files/sample.txt'

    f = open(txt_dir, "r")

    f = f.read()
```

**mycode.py**

```
import config_ru.config_utils as cu

cu.config_init()

print(cu.f)
```

On executing mycode.py, it throws the below error w.r.t "sample.txt" in "files" package

[image]

but if I change the Working directory of "my_code.py" in the script configuration from "level2" to "level1", mycode.py gets executed successfully

[image]

[image]

This is very weird because in both the cases the location of "sample.txt" remains unchanged and both the error and being forced to change the Working Directory seems to be unacceptable. Please clarify

Comment: `print(os.getcwd())` should be your friend.

Comment: *seems to be a python glitch* Very unlikely you've found a bug in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work-around is to get the path of the module you are in and apply the relative path of the resource file to that:

```py
from pathlib import Path

f = ''

def config_init():
    global f

    p = Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
    txt_dir = (p / '../files/sample.txt').resolve()

    f = open(txt_dir, "r")
    f = f.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like normal behavior. In the line

```
txt_dir = '../files/sample.txt'
```

the `..` means 'go one directory up'. So, when you are in `level2`, it will go up one level (to `level1`) and look for `files/sample.txt`, which does not exist. However, when you are in `level1`, then the `..` will bring you to the `pythonProject` dir, where it can find `files/sample.txt`

Comment: oh thanks for the clarification. Actually i thought '..' means project root folder. What is the generic way to specify the project root folder rather giving abs path because if I may have to use the project in a different system . 
I want to let the code know that "sample.txt" is in the root folder / files. Please help