# make a json available inside specific python package directory

Tags: python, json, python-module, init

I have the following python structure

```
package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── data
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── module_data1.py
    │   ├── module_data2.py
    │   ├── module_data3.py
    │   └── file.json
    └──  model
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── module_model1.py
        └── module_model2.py
```

and what I want is to make content of `file.json` available inside all `data` modules (`module_data1, module_data2, module_data3`). I have tried to read it inside `data/__init__.py`, but does not seem to be working or I do not know how to do it properly.
Here is what I put into my `data/__init__.py`

```py
## data/__init__.py

import json
with open("<path/to/file.json>", "r") as f:
    f = json.load(f)
```

But `f` is not available inside modules. Also I had to put `<path/to/file.json>` all the way from `home/...` and it would not work when I submit this `package.zip` to a `dataproc` job.

Comment: Does my answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73847226/4834) help at all?

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: @quamrana that did help finding answer to second question, by using `os` package, but still having `f` available in modules is not solved.

Comment: I made a package like yours, with your `data/__init__.py` and in my `data/module_data1.py` I added `from . import f`

Comment: It works now, though I have to import `f` in every module :)